# Регулярное выражение для выбора данных между кавычками

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, powershell

Сломал свой мозг. Пишу регулярное выражение, которое выберет мне данные из строки между кавычками, но проблема в том, что последний параметр выбирает все данные до последней кавычки, а мне нужно до первой встреченной.

Сделал следующее регулярное выражение:

```
"Min=(`"(?<minvalue>.*)`").*(max=`"(?<maxvalue>.*)`")"
```

Символ ` экранирует кавычку.

Пробовал добавлять [^`"] но не помогло :-(

Подскажите решение плиз

Comment: А в каком языке такое странное экранирование ?

Comment: Powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если между кавычками символов не очень много, используйте `«.*?»` вместо `«.*»`

Comment: Как не странно, но это помогло. В чем сила вопроса в данной конструкции?

Comment: @pincher1519 ищется минимально возможное совпадение, если вопросика нет, то ищется максимально возможное совпадение, гуглите минимальная, максимальная и жадная квантификация.

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать исключение вместо точки. Было (любой символ):

```
.*
```

Станет (любой символ, кроме кавычки):

```
[^`"]*
```